# Angularjs controller not working with routeProvider

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

My controller isn't working with ng-view when I use routeProvider. When I include the ng-controller in the body it works, but when I remove it, it doesn't. Can someone help check out my work? Help would be appreciated !
PS: I did add the script file.

Index :

```
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="js\angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js\angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script src="controller\searchControl.js"></script>
        <script src="js\data.js"></script>
      <!--  <script src="controller\searchControl.js"></script> -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="searchController">
    <header ng-include="'views/header.html'"></header>
    <main ng-view></main>
    </body>
```

Data.js :

```
      var myApp = angular.module('OneData', ['ngRoute']);

      myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){

          $routeProvider
            .when('/displayAuditorium', {
              templateUrl: 'views/displayAuditorium.html',
              controller: 'searchController'
            })
            .when('/displayExhibition', {
              templateUrl: 'views/displayExhibition.html',
              controller: 'searchController'
            }).otherwise({
              redirectTo: '/home'
            })
      }]);


      myApp.controller('searchController', ['$scope','$http', function($scope, $http){


            $scope.displayA = function() {

              $http({
                  method: 'GET',
                  url: 'https://developers.onemap.sg/publicapi/themeapi/retrieveTheme?queryName=auditoriums&token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjMsInVzZXJfaWQiOjMsImVtYWlsIjoicHVibGljQXBpUm9sZUBzbGEuZ292LnNnIiwiZm9yZXZlciI6ZmFsc2UsImlzcyI6Imh0dHA6XC9cL29tMi5kZmUub25lbWFwLnNnXC9hcGlcL3YyXC91c2VyXC9zZXNzaW9uIiwiaWF0IjoxNTM3ODYwNTIxLCJleHAiOjE1MzgyOTI1MjEsIm5iZiI6MTUzNzg2MDUyMSwianRpIjoiNmVhNzA3NTk5OWM1NGZlZjQ0ZDFkMzEyZTkyMmEzMmUifQ.q_MiRnCT_2owbMFfCcpVVSECOTellwvojAY5Wwz0xJY'
                  }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                    console.log(response.data);
                    $scope.auditoriums = response.data.SrchResults;
                  }, function errorCallback(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                  });
            };

            $scope.displayE = function() {

              $http({
                  method: 'GET',
                  url: 'https://developers.onemap.sg/publicapi/themeapi/retrieveTheme?queryName=exhibitioncentres&token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjMsInVzZXJfaWQiOjMsImVtYWlsIjoicHVibGljQXBpUm9sZUBzbGEuZ292LnNnIiwiZm9yZXZlciI6ZmFsc2UsImlzcyI6Imh0dHA6XC9cL29tMi5kZmUub25lbWFwLnNnXC9hcGlcL3YyXC91c2VyXC9zZXNzaW9uIiwiaWF0IjoxNTM4MDA5MTkzLCJleHAiOjE1Mzg0NDExOTMsIm5iZiI6MTUzODAwOTE5MywianRpIjoiNWFlNWI4MGU4ZDdmYzljZTE5ZjM2Njk2YmY0ZTg1OGQifQ.hw0a-rhRqoJubgIGl9IfP7lpn7LY-_KNQjUY8Nft1P4'
                  }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                    console.log(response.data);
                    $scope.exhibitions = response.data.SrchResults;
                  }, function errorCallback(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                  });
            };

      }]);
```

Display:

```
    <table>
        <!--    <th ng-repeat="(key,val) in auditorium">
                    {{ key }}
                  </th> -->
          <tbody>
              <tr ng-repeat="auditorium in auditoriums" ng-if="$index > 0">
                  <td>{{ auditorium.NAME }}</td>
                  <td>{{ auditorium.ADDRESSBUILDINGNAME }}</td>
                 <td>{{ auditorium.ADDRESSBLOCKHOUSENUMBER }}</td>
                  <td>{{ auditorium.ADDRESSPOSTALCODE }}</td>
                  <td>{{ auditorium.ADDRESSSTREETNAME}}</td>
              </tr>
          </tbody>
    </table>
```

ONclick function to display the code :

```
         <div class="nav-links">
          <a href="#!/displayAuditorium" ng-click="displayA()">Auditorium</a>
          <a href="#!/displayExhibition" ng-click="displayE()">Exhibition</a>
        </div>
```

Comment: did you include `angular-route` js ?

Comment: yup, i did.....

Comment: have you defined `ng-app`

Comment: i did too. I ng-app the whole html

Comment: What error it is showing on the console?

Comment: you may not need to define like this `<body ng-controller="searchController">` when you are using `routeProvider` you can specify controller and view from js

Comment: i tried doing that @Lokesh but it didnt work,

Comment: no error found @Ali786

Comment: have you imported controller src file in index? like ` <script src="searchControllerfilename.js"></script>`

Comment: @Ali786 yup. I did

Comment: it works when i write the ng-controller in the body tag, doesn't when i remove it. argh!

Comment: hmm, it seems something is missing here in the code, can you add a plunker or add all the code if possible?

Comment: done @Ali786, and the display, onclick and index are all on different html pages. Does that affect?

Comment: where did you import Data.js file in index?

Comment: in the head. updated to show @Ali786